# Problem on return matrix algorithm Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, sudoku

I'm practising my little Python skills by programming a Sudoku-Solver Algorithm.

I implemented unit test to. Now I have implemented the solver, that returns a solved matrix of the Sudoku, and I check it in the unit tests.

But the result var assigned by the return of the solver result None. I made some Breakpoints and at the end of the solver the return value ist the right solved matrix. Can someone give me a hint in which point I'm missing something?

Thanks a lot!

My sudoku Algorithm class:

```
    class SudokuSolver():

    def testTester(self):
        print('TDDisworking')
        return 'TDDisworking'

    def IsInsertPossible(self, grid:list, x:int, y:int, n:int):

        for i in range(0,9):
            if grid[i][x] == n:
                return False
        for i in range(0,9):
            if grid[y][i] == n:
                return False

        sqX = (x//3)*3
        sqY = (y//3)*3
        for i in range(0,3):
            for j in range(0,3):
                if grid[sqY+i][sqX+j] == n:
                    return False
        return True

    def Solve(self, grid:list, yRange:int, xRange:int):
        localgrid = grid
        for y in range(yRange):
            for x in range(xRange):
                if localgrid[y][x] == 0:
                    for n in range(1,10):
                        if self.IsInsertPossible(localgrid, x, y, n):
                            localgrid[y][x] = n
                            self.Solve(localgrid, yRange, xRange)
                            localgrid[y][x] = 0
                    return
        print(localgrid)
        return localgrid
```

My unit test class:

```
import unittest
from Main.SudokuSolver import SudokuSolver

class SudokuSolverTester(unittest.TestCase):

sudoku_solver = SudokuSolver()
grid = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 1, 7],
        [0, 1, 5, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 8],
        [0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0],
        [5, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 3, 4, 0],
        [3, 4, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

solgrid = [[2, 9, 4, 8, 6, 3, 5, 1, 7],
           [7, 1, 5, 4, 2, 9, 6, 3, 8],
           [8, 6, 3, 7, 5, 1, 4, 9, 2],
           [1, 5, 2, 9, 4, 7, 8, 6, 3],
           [4, 7, 9, 3, 8, 6, 2, 5, 1],
           [6, 3, 8, 5, 1, 2, 9, 7, 4],
           [9, 8, 6, 1, 3, 4, 7, 2, 5],
           [5, 2, 1, 6, 7, 8, 3, 4, 9],
           [3, 4, 7, 2, 9, 5, 1, 8, 6]]

def test_row0_results(self):
    yRange = 9
    xRange = 9
    #This result var is every time : None
    result = self.sudoku_solver.Solve(self.grid, yRange, xRange)
    self.assertListEqual(result[0], self.solgrid[0])

if __name__ == '__main__':
  unittest.main()
```

Comment: You have a `return` statement that doesn't return anything (e.g. returns `None`) after the check for a zero cell, so this is to be expected - though I don't understand how this can work at all.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the Algorithm is not working well. So I'm trying to solve the problems in it. But if you have some hints let me know I'll be happy :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. The problem was that the algorithm do not know when there are some free cells to fill. So the recursion do not stop at the end of the solution. 
If I insert a control that checks if there are the free cells the algorithm works.

Here my updated solution:

class Cell Utilities:

```
class CellUtilities():

def findNextCellToFill(self, sudoku):
    for x in range(9):
        for y in range(9):
            if sudoku[x][y] == 0:
                return x, y
    return -1, -1

def IsInsertPossible(self, sudoku, i, j, n):
    rowOk = all([n != sudoku[i][x] for x in range(9)])
    if rowOk:
        columnOk = all([n != sudoku[x][j] for x in range(9)])
        if columnOk:
            secTopX, secTopY = 3 * (i // 3), 3 * (j // 3)
            for x in range(secTopX, secTopX + 3):
                for y in range(secTopY, secTopY + 3):
                    if sudoku[x][y] == n:
                        return False
            return True
    return False
```

class SudokuSolverI:

```
from Main.CellUtilities import CellUtilities
class SudokuSolverI():

cellUtil = CellUtilities()

def solveSudoku(self, sudoku, row_i=0, col_j=0):
    row_i, col_j = self.cellUtil.findNextCellToFill(sudoku)
    if row_i == -1:
        return True
    for num in range(1, 10):
        if self.cellUtil.IsInsertPossible(sudoku, row_i, col_j, num):
            sudoku[row_i][col_j] = num
            if self.solveSudoku(sudoku, row_i, col_j):
                return True
            sudoku[row_i][col_j] = 0
    return False
```

Thanks all who helps me to find the solution!